# Tag synonym vs. renaming

Tags: discussion

while I know about tag synonyms I'm not exactly sure in this case if I'm using it right.

I proposed ai to be a synonym of artificial-intelligence, since at least one person keeps using it.  is this correct or should I continue to replace the tag when I see questions with it?

Answer (score 9):

That sounds like an appropriate use of a synonym to me.  A synonym should be defined when there are multiple ways to describe a concept *and* when typing one of them wouldn't offer an auto-complete to the other.  So, for example, don't create synonyms between singular and plural forms; if you start typing either the tag will be suggested.  But if the words are very different -- meteorology -> weather, cartography -> map-making, or (IMO) ai -> artificial-intelligence, a synonym is helpful.

Comment: OK, that's what I thought, but then I didn't know if an abbreviation (even a well known one) would be acceptable.

Answer (score 4):

Monica is (as usual!) right, in my opinion. It seems like you're fine.

Confession time: I edited out the [ai](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ai) tag from the question it was used on - before seeing this meta post. My reason was that the [artifical-intelligence](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/artifical-intelligence) tag already exists and doesn't seem to have any problems; I didn't think it was necessary to have an abbreviated tag - though if anyone wants to rollback the edit, that's fine with me. But I don't think we need to have tags that are this similar.

If the [ai](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ai) tag is kept, I think it should by all means be a synonym of [artifical-intelligence](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/artifical-intelligence). Wish I had the required rep to vote for that!

Answer (score 3):

The problem with editing the tags of all faulty questions is that people might still continue to use it in the future. Thus, every time a new question appear, we would need to change the tag. It is much easier to use 2 tags and put them as synonym in my opinion.

Unless someone make a world building question related to Adobe illustrator. (.ai is the extension of the files)

Comment: This is why I finally made made a suggested synonym I got tired of replacing it all the time.